# Wrong Textbook Answer for $\lambda$?

Tags: statistics

> Given a rock that contains $10^{20}$ atoms of a particular substance. Each
>   atom has an exponentially distributed lifetime with a half-life of one
>   century. How many centuries must pass before:
>
> a) It is most likely 100 atoms remain

**Textbook Answer:**

[image]

Shouldn't $\lambda$ be:

[image]

?

**Edit 1 (question from textbook):**

[image]

Comment: but you must compute $t$ not $\lambda$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have already computed $t=59.79$ using the same method as the textbook, but it does not match the textbook's answer because we have different $\lambda$. So I want to know if they got $\lambda$ wrong

Comment: i think the solution given is correct, so fare i see yet

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  If so, could you tell me how they got that $\lambda$ value?  Thanks!

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life for the solution of this problem

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life tells me that $\lambda = ln(2)$ which is the same as my $\lambda$, but not the textbook's.

Comment: ok then is a typo in the solution of your textbook, i got the same $\lambda$ as you

Comment: @A_for_Abacus : Standard notation is $\ln(2)$ or $\ln 2,$ not $ln(2).$ The use of the backslash not only deitalicizes it, but also results in proper spacing in expressions like $a\ln b$ or $a\ln(b),$ where I include both of those so that you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way the question is phrased, I wouldn't bother with $e$ or with $\lambda.$ Those are needed when you talk about instantaneous rates of change, but the question doesn't require that.
\begin{align}
& 10^{20} \times \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^\text{number of centuries} = 100 \\[15pt]
& \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^\text{number of centuries} = \frac{100}{10^{20}} = 10^{-18} \\[15pt]
& 2^\text{number of centuries} = 10^{18} \\[15pt]
& \text{number of centuries} = \log_2 (10^{18}) = 18 \log_2 10.
\end{align}

Your solution also appears to be correct. You have $\lambda = -\log \frac 1 2$ (where $\log$ means $\ln$ or $\log_e,$ as in your textbook), so
\begin{align}
100 & = 10^{20} e^{\left(\ln\frac 1 2\right) t} = 10^{20} \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^t
\end{align}